# Creating "visualizers" for my types in C++ for vscode debugger

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

In the instruction (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) I see that VSCode can use a ".natvis" file.  It then refers to docs from Visual Studio, so most of the usage information does not apply but there is a rather brief section on the syntax of the file.

- It says that "Natvis customizations work with classes and structs, but not typedefs."  but what is the situation with `using` type aliases?  The type shown to me in the Variables pane does involve `using` to create the name that the code subsequently consumes, though it's actually defined in internal namespaces and template aliases.  Do I need to unravel the name as it would be without any `using`s?
- It gives a simple example of a template, but that example uses a type argument and only one template argument.  What about non-type arguments?  Does the `*` work on the string of the name to match or only on individual components of the name?

  ```
  template <int S, int F>
  class Decimal { ... };
  ```
- The information about turning on diagnostics in Visual Studio 2019 (on Windows!) is completely irrelevant to VSCode.  How do I troubleshoot?
- As noted above, I have a `Decimal` class that represents fixed-point numbers in integers.  How can I craft the output I want when functions can't be called?  String manipulation would work, once the integer member (field) is formed into a string for display, I need merely insert a decimal point at `F`<sup>th</sup> position from the right.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm looking at doing this for my fixed point library...